# How to prevent old URL's and a ? being included in a 301 redirected URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In summary, we're currently having issues with our htaccess file. 301 redirects are going through to the new described URL but in addition the new URL is followed by a ? and the old URL. How can we get rid of the ? and previous URL so they don't appear as an ending.

None of the examples we've found re this issue online appear to work. Can anyone please offer some advice? Can we use a RewriteRule to stop this happening?

Here's a summary of the htaccess file

```
# begin redirects
# There are redirects of a number of old pages. Here's a sample of them.

redirect 301 /index.html http://www.petersommer.com/
redirect 301 /escorted-archaeological-tours/turkey/western-lycia-cruise-july/ http://www.petersommer.com/escorted-archaeological-tours/

RewriteRule ^gallery/main.php$  http://www.petersommer.com/gallery/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^pdf/how_to_book.pdf$  http://www.petersommer.com/pdf/how-to-book-holiday.pdf [R=301,L]

# end redirects

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond $1 !^(images|system|themes|pdf|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

    RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure what isn't working or what needs to be done to fix it. I assume it must be something in the Rewrite Rules or we need to add in some Rewrite Rules to fix it.

All the redirects are unfortunately adding a ? and the old URL to the end of the new redirected URL. So for example:

The redirect 301 of `/tours2006.html` to 
`/escorted-archaeological-tours/`
goes through to `/escorted-archaeological-tours/?/tours2006.html` 
instead of just `/escorted-archaeological-tours/`

All are following the same pattern - unfortunately.

If you can see any glitches in the Rewrite Rules or can identify something we need to add I will be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably have noted, the two redirects expressed as `RewriteRule` work as intended, whereas the two `redirect` directives append the old path.

**What I believe happens**

- mod_rewrite kicks in, redirects `gallery/main.php` and `pdf/how_to_book.pdf` if necessary, and then rewrites every other URL to `/index.php?/the_requested_path` and ends there (the L flag). Note the query parameter
- mod_alias takes its turn, sees it has to redirect /index.html for example, which is redirected as instructed. But, by default, Apache redirects with the query parameters appended, in this case ?/index.html

**What you could do**

- append a ? at the end of the redirect directives (works for RewriteRule, not tested on redirect)

  ```
  redirect 301 /index.html http://www.petersommer.com/?
  ```
- transform your redirect directives in Rewrite rules

  ```
  RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.petersommer.com/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^escorted-archaeological-tours/turkey/western-lycia-cruise-july/?$ http://www.petersommer.com/escorted-archaeological-tours/ [R=301,L]
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to assist. Unfortunately I still can't make it work. Would you alter the order in the file? Any other suggestions? Appreciate your input. Best wishes, Peter

Comment: @petersommer I just checked the /index.html on your site, the redirections are working as intended. Maybe a cache problem? Or did you find  another solution?